# How to add a shading pattern to a custom shape

Tags: itext

I have drawn an equilateral triangle as follows using iText

```
canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
int x = start.getX();
int y = start.getY();
canvas.moveTo(x,y);        
canvas.lineTo(x + side,y);
canvas.lineTo(x + (side/2), (float)(y+(side*Math.sin(convertToRadian(60)))));
canvas.closePathStroke();
```

I wish to multi color gradient in this shape i.e. fill it with shading comprising of `BaseColor.PINK` and `BaseColor.BLUE`. I just can't find a way to do this with iText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an example called [ShadedFill](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ShadedFill) that fills the triangle you are drawing using a shading pattern that goes from pink to blue as show in the [shaded_fill.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/shaded_fill.pdf):

[image]

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
float x = 36;
float y = 740;
float side = 70;
PdfShading axial = PdfShading.simpleAxial(writer, x, y,
        x + side, y, BaseColor.PINK, BaseColor.BLUE);
PdfShadingPattern shading = new PdfShadingPattern(axial);
canvas.setShadingFill(shading);
canvas.moveTo(x,y);        
canvas.lineTo(x + side, y);
canvas.lineTo(x + (side / 2), (float)(y + (side * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3))));
canvas.closePathFillStroke();
```

As you can see, you need to create a `PdfShading` object. I created an axial shading that varies from  pink to blue from the coordinate `(x, y)` to the coordinate `(x + side, y)`. With this axial shading, you can create a `PdfShadingPattern` that can be used as a parameter of the `setShadingFill()` method to set the fill color for the `canvas`.

See [ShadedFill](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ShadedFill) for the full source code.

Comment: That's what i wanted, perfectly. Thanks alot