# Add Gradient Shading using Stamper

Tags: itext

I have code that uses iTextSharp to add a variety of colored rectangles to an *existing* PDF document using the `PdfStamper` object with code like the following:

```
Dim reader As New PdfReader(byte_contets_of_PDF_file)
Dim stamper As New PdfStamper(reader, someOutputBuffer)
Dim under As PdfContentByte = stamper.GetUnderContent(pageNumber)
under.SetColorFill(BaseColors.RED)
under.Rectangle(x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight)
under.Fill()
```

This works swimmingly for drawing monochromatic rectangles on an existing PDF document, but I was hoping I could place rectangles that use a color gradient.

My research has turned up examples using the `PdfShading` and `PdfShadingPattern` objects, but those require a `PdfWriter`. To my understanding, the `PdfWriter` is used for creating new PDFs and not for updating existing PDFs.

Is it possible to add rectangles to an existing PDF document that have a gradient?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just using the `stamper.Writer` property which will give you the underlying PdfWriter instance?

Comment: @ChrisHaas, that was exactly what I needed to know, namely how to get the underlying PdfWriter from the stamper. Thanks, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have read the answer to this question: [How to add a shading pattern to a custom shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586093/how-to-add-a-shading-pattern-to-a-custom-shape)

I assume that your problem is that you don't know which parameter to use instead of `writer`.

If that is the case, use 'stamper.GetOverContent(p)' instead of `writer.DirectContent` and use `stamper.Writer` instead of `writer`:

```
int p = 1; // or whatever page number applies
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(p);
float x = 36;
float y = 740;
float side = 70;
PdfShading axial = PdfShading.SimpleAxial(writer, x, y,
    x + side, y, BaseColor.PINK, BaseColor.BLUE);
PdfShadingPattern shading = new PdfShadingPattern(axial);
canvas.SetShadingFill(shading);
canvas.MoveTo(x,y);        
canvas.LineTo(x + side, y);
canvas.LineTo(x + (side / 2), (float)(y + (side * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3))));
canvas.ClosePathFillStroke();
```